# React useState is one step behind

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

So I have read a bunch of other posts here about the topic, but I'm still unable to fix my problem based on the answers I have seen. I'm creating two counters and using their state as values in an array (just to play around with React, no practical or logical use of this) and I would like to pass the counter array to another component. However, the values in the array are not displaying the updated state (ie in a console log), but is always one step behind. I know this is because it is asynchronous and that I should use useEffect in some way, but I simply cannot figure out how I should do this to make it work as intended. I'm pretty new to React - any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function Counter() {
    const [count1, setCount1State] = useState(0);
    const [count2, setCount2State] = useState(0);
    

    let counters = [
        { name: 1, count: count1State },
        { name: 2, count: count2State },
       
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        //WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE TO HAVE COUNTERS HOLDING THE LATEST STATE VALUES?
    }, [count1, count2]);

    function increaseCounter(name: number) {
        switch (name) {
            case 1: {
                setCount1State(count1 + 1);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                setCount2State(count2 + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function decreaseCounter(name: number) {
        switch (name) {
            case 1:        
                    setCount1State(count1 - 1);
                    break;
            }

            case 2:
                    setCount2State(count2 - 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no console log in your snippet, so it's unclear what and where your problem lies. If you are simply trying to log the current counter values then `useEffect(() => console.log(count1, count2), [count1, count2]);` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use the hook in case you just expect re-rendering of the component (or element included into JSX) representing the state. It updates right after the state has been changed. You just should send the value like this:

```
// if component is used:
return <Component state={state} changeState={setState} />
// in case of JSX element usage:
return <div>{state}</div>
```

UseEffect is for some additonal work like other states updating, DOM changes, fetching data etc. Using it, be very careful with the list of dependencies. This is your example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // fetching data etc
}, [count1, count2]);
```

Here you set count1 and count2 states as dependencies for the hook. In other words, the hook fires when any of those states changes. That means you should not change any of the states inside the hook, otherwise you will get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need useEffect.

```
function Counter() {
    const [count1, setCount1State] = useState(0);
    const [count2, setCount2State] = useState(0);

    function increaseCounter(name: number) {
        switch (name) {
            case 1: {
                setCount1State(count1 + 1);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                setCount2State(count2 + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function decreaseCounter(name: number) {
        switch (name) {
            case 1:        
                    setCount1State(count1 - 1);
                    break;
            }

            case 2:
                    setCount2State(count2 - 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return {
    <>
            <h3>Counter1: {count1}</h3>
            <h3>Counter2: {count2}</h3>
            <Button onClick={() => increaseCounter(1)}>IncreaseCounter1</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => increaseCounter(2)}>IncreaseCounter2</Button>
    </>};
    };
```

and so on